# How can i populate cells in all columns - DataTable c#

Tags: c#, datatable, populate

I have a DataTable like this.

```
--------------------------------------------
|   date   |   a   |   b   |   c   |   d   |
--------------------------------------------
|24.12.2018|       |       |       |       |
--------------------------------------------
```

And I have this code

```
var topla = Dao.Sum<x>(
    a => ((a.Orj_Fiyat_VergiDahil * a.Ana_Miktar) * a.Kur) - a.Iskonto_Tutar, 
    a => (urunidler.Contains(a.Urun_Id)) && (a.Tarih <= Zaman && a.Tarih >= Zaman1));
```

I wanna insert topla to all columns. I got one row. Columns' names are changable.

Like this, if topla equals 5, 6, 15, 200 or anyting for each column:

> ```
>     --------------------------------------------
>     |   date   |   a   |   b   |   c   |   d   |
>     --------------------------------------------
>     |24.12.2018|   5   |   6   |   15  |  200  |
>     --------------------------------------------
> ```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want a pivot table.  So you want to group by date and then each item in the group will be placed in a different column.

Comment: I want to group by ID.

Comment: Where is the ID?  You just shows a date.  Show better example of your inputs.